# During installation of lightgbm it says that you should install cmake first, while I have installed it

Tags: ubuntu, cmake, lightgbm

I want to install the GPU version of lightgbm on Ubuntu, based on the following command:

```
pip install lightgbm --install-option=--gpu
```

During installation, an error is occurred saying "Please install CMake first". After installing CMake, I get the same error again. To be sure that CMake is installed, I run the following command and get the correct version of the installed CMake:

```
/opt/cmake/bin/cmake -version
```

What is the possible reason of this error?

Comment: Is CMake in your path? What are the results of `which cmake`?

Comment: @CinderBiscuits '/usr/local/bin/cmake'

Comment: Looks like your system version of cmake is too old. Please give the output of the following 3 commands: `cmake --version`, `/usr/local/bin/cmake --version`, `/opt/cmake/bin/cmake --version`

Comment: @SteveLorimer Actually, I installed the latest stable release. All the mentioned commands return 3.9.4 as the version.

Comment: According to the docs it should work then. Perhaps try build from source? Instructions [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/tree/master/python-package): `git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM.git
cd LightGBM/python-package
python setup.py install --gpu`

Comment: @SteveLorimer The same error occurred while installing from source. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10):

I had same issue too, on my M1 MacBook Air. I solve this problem by using `brew`. Firstly, I ran `brew install gcc` then `brew install CMake` because of dependicies. After that, I ran `brew install lightgbm` on my IDE's terminal. Finally, run `pip install lightgbm` command on my IDE's terminal and I can succesfully import lightgbm.

Comment: I had the same on my M2 Macbook Pro, maybe it is an Apple Silicon issue?

Answer (score 7):

I got exactly this error, on Ubuntu 16.04 with CUDA installed and cmake version 3.5.1. In my case, despite the "Please install CMake" error, the issue was:

- The necessary boost libraries were not installed, and
- cmake was not able to find OpenCL.

I was able to install LightGBM for Python by doing the following:

```
# Install boost libraries.
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
# Get LightGBM source.
git clone --recursive https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM.git
cd LightGBM/python-package/
# cmake specifying locations of OpenCL files.
sudo cmake -DUSE_GPU=1 -DOpenCL_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64/libOpenCL.so -DOpenCL_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/include/ ..
# Compile.
sudo make
# Install for Python, using what we just compiled.
python setup.py install --precompile
```

After that I was able to run Python and `import lightgbm` successfully.

## Didn't help?

"Please install CMake" can mask other errors. To see more detail about what is going wrong, in `LightGBM/python-package/setup.py`, in the function `silent_call`, change the line

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=shut_up)
```

to

```
subprocess.check_output(cmd)
```

and run

```
python setup.py install --gpu
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on pip 7.1.0.

An update to pip 9.0.1 solved the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In jupyter notebook run

```
!pip uninstall numba -y
!conda install numba -y

!pip uninstall numpy -y
!conda install numpy -y
```

In Mac open terminal and run the following

```
brew install gcc
brew install CMake
brew install lightgbm
```

Finally go back to notebook and run

```
!pip install lightgbm
```